# The System cannot find the path specified yiic command

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, wamp, yii

I have asked the same question on stackoverflow but could not get some good response. I am not sure if it is right to question here.
 I have been trying last night about this error. The error comes when i am standing in a directory and i want to access a file yiic but error comes

> The System cannot find the path specified
>   My system:

1. Windows 8.1 64 bit
2. wamp server 3.0.06 64bit
3. PHP version 5.6.25(used by wamp server)
4. Yii 1.1.19

**My file strucure:**
C-->wamp64-->www->yii-->framework

**Problem:**
I am standing in framework folder. When i type this command to create a new yii project. I think this is the problem with my windows, not with yiic or php.

```
C:\wamp64\www\yii\framework> yiic webapp C:\wamp64\www\testapp
```

I get this error

> The System cannot find the path specified

**Things I have tried so far:**

1. Ran cmd as administrator but same result
2. unlocked the yii zipped file, I have read that on some site that windows sometimes blocks .bat files in zipped file but same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### When I type this command to create a new yii project I get an error

> C:\wamp64\www\yii\framework> yiic webapp C:\wamp64\www\testapp

According to [Yii 1.1: To configure Yii path in Windows platform](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/171/to-configure-yii-path-in-windows-platform/) the command should be:

```
E:\xampp\php>php.exe E:/xampp/htdocs/yii/framework/yiic webapp E:/xampp/htdocs/blog
```

Notes:

- There is `/yiic` added after `framework`.
- The command uses `/` instead of `\`
- `php` is used to exectute `yiic`